# Showing that if A is a diagonalizable matrix then any matrix that can be achieved by a set of elementary operations on A is also diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Sorry for the long title, English is not my first language and I couldn't find a shorter description of the question.

I need help proving / disproving this question:

A is a matrix, B is the matrix acquired from A after doing a set of elementary operations. A is diagonalizable, prove or disprove B is diagonalizable.

My attempt is as following:

If a is diagonalizable then there is a diagonal matrix D and an inversible matrix P that follows this equation $\mathrm{D=P^{-1}AP}$. Also, you can show B as a multiplication of multiple elementary matrices followed by A ($\mathrm{B=\phi_k(I)\phi_{k-1}(I)...\phi_{1}(I)A}$), because every elementary matrix is inversible, we can multiply by the inverse matrices from the left and receive this equation: $\mathrm{A=\phi_k(I)^{-1}\phi_{k-1}(I)^{-1}...\phi_{1}(I)^{-1}B}$, after combining the two equations we get $\mathrm{D=P^{-1}\phi_k(I)^{-1}\phi_{k-1}(I)^{-1}...\phi_{1}(I)^{-1}BP}$ but I couldn't find a way to continue my answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

It is easy to verify that $A$ is diagonal, $B$ is obtained by adding the first column of $A$ to its second column, but $B$ is not diagonalizable (it is a Jordan block).

Comment: Got it, if I get this kind of question though, how am I supposed to get into it, I tried to prove it generally because its harder to me to see a matrix and tell if it is diagonalizable (B), we haven't learned about Jordan blocks yet.

Comment: @user3731180 In my opinion, you need to have a good understanding about the Jordan canonical form to deal with problems that relevant to diagonalizable/non-diagonalizable. The key observation to this question is that Jordan blocks are not diagonalizable.